# Unable to load stylesheets

Tags: css, wordpress

I customized the colors of my theme using `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_add_inline_style` in this way

```
//enqueue script and style
    function hb_enqueue_link(){

    $templUri = get_template_directory_uri();

    $uriCss = $templUri.'/css/';

    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_colors_css',$uriCss.'custom-colors.css' );

    //custom style
            $hb_firstColor = get_theme_mod( 'firstColor' );

    $hb_style_colors_css = "
        .first-color-op{
            background-color : rgba(".hb_rgba_transform( $hb_firstColor, 0.75 ).");             
        }
    ";

    //add style
    wp_add_inline_style( 'custom_colors_css', $hb_style_colors_css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hb_enqueue_link' );
```

Also insert the function that transforms colors from hex in to rgba,so if it would to someone:

```
//transform hex in rgba
function hb_rgba_transform( $hex, $op ){

    if( strpos($hex, "#") == 0):

        $r = hexdec( substr( $hex, 1, 2 ) );

        $g = hexdec( substr( $hex, 3, 2 ) );

        $b = hexdec( substr( $hex, 5, 2 ) );

        $rgba = $r.','.$g.','.$b.','.$op;

        return $rgba;

    else:

        return '0,0,0,1';

    endif;

}
```

the problem and that gives me this error on mozilla [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQA4u.png), in English translates to

> impossible to load the stylesheet. http//....

this error does also other browser
where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? I mean, is /css/ dir really on root of /heartbeat/ theme?

Comment: yes,I have other wp_enqueue_style that work but I have not included there

Comment: Is this a child theme?

Comment: no, is in function.php parent page

Comment: Does it work if you remove everything below `//custom style` in that function?

Comment: no. I had already tried this, but I always make the same mistake

Comment: How can I contact a wordpress administrator to resolve this?

Comment: I found a error`background-color = rgba` instead`background-color : rgba`, now it works but I do not even charge custom-colors.css

Comment: practically rather than adding to custom-color.css, add in to inline